# How to convert System.DateTime to related amount of minutes?

Tags: .net, datetime

I need to convert a variable from System.DateTime type to related amount of minutes of integer type E.g.

> 4:00AM = 240 minutes

(amount of minutes from the beginning of the day to 4:00AM),

> 12:00 = 720 minutes, 
>   23:00 = 1380 minutes.

Is there any .net utility function?

Comment: Try `TimeSpan` buddy

Comment: Does the date part of the `DateTime` need to be taken into consideration? On the dates when daylight saving time begins/ends there may not be exactly 240 minutes between midnight and 4am.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`TimeSpan.TotalMinutes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes(v=vs.110).aspx), you get the timespan from  [`DateTime.TimeOfDay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
int minutes = (int) now.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes;
```

Comment: Looks like this is what i need. Thank you.